# JWT Token validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to perform JWT validation for each action excepting the LogIn and Register actions, but I cannot find a way to do it in action filters, as i need the token and it's on this.Request.Headers.
This is the validation method which works fine:

```
try
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    string sToken = token.Substring(7, token.Length - 7);

    if (!tokenHandler.CanReadToken(sToken))
    {
        return false;
    }

    JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = tokenHandler.ReadToken(sToken) as JwtSecurityToken;

    if (jwtToken == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    TokenValidationParameters parameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        ValidAudience = "http://localhost",
        ValidIssuer = "http://localhost",
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(StandardValues.SecretKey))
    };

    SecurityToken securityToken;
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(sToken, parameters, out securityToken);

    if (principal == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return false;
}

return true;
```

And I have multiple controllers on which I want to perform the validation.
Please let me know how can I perform this validation outside and before the actions, (into an action filter or another way) while sending the token as parameter for validation method.

Comment: Where is this block of code being called from?

Comment: please include more context as @DaveC pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our ASP.Net WebApi we use the following for validating our tokens:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = $"https://{Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppServiceNameOutput")}",
            ValidAudience = $"https://{Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppServiceNameOutput")}",
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("SigningKey"))),
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = context =>
            {
                var tokenBlackList = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenBlackList>();
                var tokenParser = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITokenParser>();
                var bearer = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bearer))
                {
                    bearer = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
                }

                var token = tokenParser.GetBearerTokenFromAuthHeaderString(bearer);
                if (tokenBlackList.TokenIsBlackListed(token).Result)
                {
                    context.Fail("Token has expired");
                }
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

Then on each controller action we specify whether the endpoint should be authorised or not, and which policies are allowed access.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ManagerOnly")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Update([FromBody] UpdateAppRequest request)
```

Comment: Thanks, this example is perfect! Also, the validation method returns a bool. If false then user must be redirected to LogIn page. Can this be done from here?

Comment: Well calling the requests with an invalid token would return a 403 response code if I am not mistaken. Not sure how you could handle the redirection though. Check every response in your app maybe.

Comment: You're right. It will return 401 though, which is perfect for redirecting from the frontend